# Fake a mount to local folder

Tags: mount, symbolic-link, macos-catalina, apfs

Every so often I need to locally debug Groovy scripts that write files to a subfolder in `/mnt` on the server. Is there a way to fake this mount on my local machine to another folder (in `/tmp`) so that I don't have to alter the scripts for debugging (which is cumbersome and error-prone as I could forget to change this back before "copy-paste deployment")? I played a little with symlinks and `diskutil mount` but couldn't get it to work.

I obviously know this is what configuration is for but that is out of my control for this project.

Comment: @Smock It is not from a server, all is locally. I just want to make a path `/mnt/somefolder` work locally, could point to any other local folder.

Comment: @Smock Yes, it doens't allow me to create symlinks to the `/mnt` path. `ln: /mnt: Read-only file system`

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X Catalina. Doesn't seem to support the `--bind` option.

Comment: Argh. totally didn't see the macos tag :-/ all bets are off then!